# How to use custom navigation buttons for royalslider

Tags: javascript, slider

I have a (royal)slider, I need to use the next/prev nav buttons to be out of the slider div.
Lets say I have the navigation nav buttons in my footer.

```
<div class="my-prev-button"></div>
<div class="my-next-button"></div>
```

Here is some documentation but I don't know how to use this!
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api

How can I make these two buttons work with the slider (while it is outside)

```
<script id="addJS">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#slider-with-blocks').royalSlider({
    arrowsNav: true,
    arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
    fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
    controlNavigationSpacing: 0,
    controlNavigation: 'none',
    imageScaleMod: 'none',
    autoScaleSlider: false,
    imageScalePadding: 0,
    slidesSpacing: 0,
    autoHeight: false, 
    blockLoop: true,
    loop: true,
    numImagesToPreload: 4,
    transitionType: 'fade',
    autoPlay: {
        enabled: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,        
    },
    block: {
        delay: 400
    }
  });
});
</script>

<div class="slider">
    <div id="slider-with-blocks" class="royalSlider rsMinW">
        <div class="rsContent" data-rsDelay="5000">
        some div and img here..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your current Situation,What problem you are facing?

Comment: The slider works, but the nav to start the next slide needs to be outside the slider div. I don't know how to use the API. This script adds the next/prev buttons in the <div class="royalslider">.

Comment: Is this plugin Free? Can i see it for demo ,to solve your problem,Or you can give link to me so i can solve it

Comment: I have a z-index problem (safari) so I would like to use the API for next/prev outside the royalslider div. Here is the site: http://tinyurl.com/o2wzzp5

Comment: You will have to move The Their , arrow (Right,left) to Specific position you want using CSS

Comment: it is placed into it by the script, I can't do it by CSS, safari has z-index problems. Banner needs to be below the main content but the arrows need to be on top. there is no way to do this

Comment: navigateByClick event of that slider you need to use according to me. And Fire it on click of div you have written above

Comment: can't get it to work argh. think I will search a other fader/slider or fix the z-index. combining top and main div and then I can play with z-index working for all browsers..

Answer (score 1):

Style your Next and Previous div's as per your need and use below code after initializing royal-slider:

```
// get hold of royal-slider object
var slider = $('#slider-with-blocks').data('royalSlider');
// previous button
$('.my-prev-button').on('click', function(){
   slider.prev();
});
$('.my-next-button').on('click', function(){
   slider.next();
});
```

You can find more API's here
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api

Answer (score 0):

here an example of the solution:
 http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/slider-in-laptop/